# Creating dynamic page variables for a statewide report

Tags: adobe-illustrator, indesign-scripting

I need to develop a report that publishes data collected from all of the counties in the state. The layout format for each county is the same but the graphs and charts with ten data points vary. I have three counties per page. How can I automate and populate each county format with graphics that change with the imported data across all the pages?

The different values for each county will need to not only change the text, but the object as well. For example a pie chart.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Adobe Illustrator's Variables feature along with the VariableImporter.jsx script to bring in variable text content, images, graph data as well as visibility variables.

Here's where you get the script:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Silly-V/Adobe-Illustrator/master/Variable%20Importer/VariableImporter.jsx

You can view a video here for the script's usage:
https://youtu.be/eCBrK8tZAXQ

And see my own interactive variable result sample here:
http://silly-v.github.io/Interactive%20VDP/fish-crow.html
Read the description here:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/illustrator-variable-data-extended-techniques-interactive-vasily-hall/

For the announcement when the VI script began to support graphs, here's that article:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/variableimporterjsx-now-supports-graph-variables-vasily-hall/

Sounds like an interesting report!